# do I have to manually release (with ARC) a target view controller?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In my program I often have to manually set up a destination view controller so that I can populate it with data. This works fine, but when watching the Profiler as I go back and forth between the source controller and the destination controller, my allocations are skyrocketing. I am using ARC. I know it could also be how I am setting up things in that destination, but I was also wondering -- do I not have to get rid of the destination controller I set up when coming back to the source controller?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //Pull which topic the user clicked on from the table view
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.myTableView2
                                indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray * topicArray = [[myTopicLoader arrayOfFinishedCategories] objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];

    //Create a temporary NSObject Topic to send to the detail view controller
    //Set it to the Topic in the array based on which row the user clicked on
    //(The tableview was populated with the same array)
    topic *tempTopic = [topicArray objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];

    //If they clicked on one that has details to show and is purchased, load the detail view controller
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTopicDetails"]) {
        //Set up a destination view controller
        topicDetailController *topicDetailController = [segue destinationViewController];

        //Set its topic to the temporary one we set up here
        topicDetailController.currentTopic = tempTopic;
    }else {
           //If they clicked on one that does not have details because it is not yet purchased, load
           //the purchase view controller instead
           purchaseDetailController *purchaseDetailController = [segue destinationViewController];

           //And set its topic to the temporary one we set up here.
           purchaseDetailController.currentTopic = tempTopic;


    }

}
```

Most of my excess allocations are either:

29717   0xaa8a600   __NSArrayM  00:28.703.069   •   32  UIKit   _UITapRecognizerCommonInit

or

1069    0x15d5e650  Malloc 32 Bytes 00:29.254.799   •   32  libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_copy_internal

Which I guess could be from some of the pre-built things I am using (a book controller and google's XML parser). But I wanted to check and see if maybe not getting rid of the destination controller had something to do with it.

Comment: Normally, ARC should handle the releases and you should not have leaks. Just to be clear here, can you put more details on how you are profiling: What instrument are you using, what settings for that instruments and what column of data you are looking at in that instrument where you are seeing an increase in allocations as you go back and forth?

Comment: I am using the allocations tool, and setting heap shots between iterations of pushing the view controller and then popping it right back off. It grows by about 3mb each time.

Comment: And by the way -- a lot of what is allocated are UIKit items, i.e. UITextView's. Should ARC be getting rid of those? Autoreleasepooling did not change it either.

Comment: But which column of allocations are you seeing growing: #living, #transitory, #overall?

Comment: Well I was comparing the snapshots of the heaps for new memory allocated, but when looking at the column view the living is growing.